# Optimizing SOQL Query with Formula Field in the Conditional

Tags: soql, formula-field, lookup

We are receiving data from two sources that we are supposed to match using an identifier provided by the clients, 'GUID'.  The two sources go into two custom objects in salesforce, Activities and Eligibilities.

I created a trigger that links records across the objects together via a lookup field with Activities as the child, and everything works properly.

However, one of the clients is sending us data where the 'GUID' identifier is actually the last 36 digits in a longer string.  There is a formula field, 'i_guid_only__c' that extracts the GUID.  Inside the trigger, I populate a Set with all the GUIDs from the new records, and use that to query for matching GUIDs on the other object.

```
List<Norton_User_Eligibility__c> matches = [Select id, i_guid_only__c From Norton_User_Eligibility__c WHERE i_guid_only__c in :actGUIDs];
```

The problem is, with ~70k Eligibility records, that query takes over a minute to run.  Even adding a single new Activity record can take way too long, and bulk upload processes take an insane amount of time or fail to run at all.

I'm currently working in a sandbox to optimize the trigger / query, but have yet to find an optimized or better solution.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the SOQL in the trigger of Norton_User_Eligibility__c SObject or some other object.

Comment: I think you should look at preprocessing that guid field to extract the required value into a static text field, marked as an external id so it gets indexed.

Comment: @CasparHarmer I think that's exactly what I'm going to do.